# jQuery deferredでfailが呼ばれない

Tags: javascript, jquery

jQueryのDeferredを使う下記コードを作成しましたが、400エラーの時にfailが呼ばれると思いましたが、consoleに`GET http://localhost:3000/api/favorite?id=100 400 (Bad Request)`とでて処理が実行されません。200,201の時はdoneが実行されます。

コード

```
$(function(){
    $(document).on('click', '#add-fav', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        addFav(id)
            .done(
                function(data){
                    Materialize.toast(data.name+'を登録しました', 3000);
                })
            .fail(
                function(err){
                    Materialize.toast(err.reason, 3000);
                }
            );
    });

    $(document).on('click', '#del-fav', function(){
        var id = $(this).data("id");
        delFav(id)
            .done(
                function(){
                    Materialize.toast("削除しました。", 3000);
                })
            .fail(
                function(err){
                    Materialize.toast(err.reason, 3000);
                }
            );
    });
});

// お気に入りを追加する。
function addFav(id){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/favorite",
        type: "GET",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        dataType: "json",
        success: defer.resolve,
        error: defer.reject
    });
    return defer.promise();
}

// お気に入りを削除する。
function delFav(id){
    var defer = $.Deferred();
    $.ajax({
        url: "/api/favorite",
        type: "DELETE",
        data: {
            id: id
        },
        success: defer.resolve,
        error: defer.reject
    });
    return defer.promise();
}
```

エラー時にfailが呼ばれるようにするにはどのようにすればいいのでしょうか。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`fail()` に渡したコールバック関数は正しく呼び出されていますが、あなたが期待したような引数は渡されていないため、正しく動作していません。

`deferred.reject()` にn個の引数を渡した場合、同じように `promise.fail()` のコールバック関数もn個の引数で呼び出されます。今回 [`$.ajax()`](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) はエラーハンドラに指定した `reject()` を `(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` という3つの引数で呼び出したため、同じように `fail()` のコールバック関数も `(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)` と3つの引数で呼び出されます。

コールバック関数は呼び出されたものの、第一引数である `jqXHR` に `reason` というプロパティは存在しないため `undefined` となり、期待したように通知が行われなかったのでしょう。

ちなみにjQuery1.5以降 [`$.ajax()` はPromise互換のオブジェクトを返すので](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/#jqXHR)、直接 `$.ajax(...).fail(...)` とできますが、この場合も前述のように3つの引数という形で呼び出されます。

```js
$.ajax({url: 'http://example.com/undefined'})
  .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    alert("jqXHR: " + jqXHR + ", textStatus: " + textStatus + ", errorThrown:" + errorThrown);
  });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

なお、resolve/reject時に複数の引数を渡せるのはjQueryのDeferredに限った話で、Promise/A+やES2015のPromiseには一つの引数しか渡せません。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。
jqXHRのresponseJSON.reasonから結果を取得できました。